# Import in a module fails because __name__ is __main__

Tags: python, python-import

Here is my project structure:

```
Project
   main.py
   myPackage/
      subfolder1/
         __init__.py
         script11.py
         script12.py
      subfolder2/
         __init__.py
         script2.py
   __init__.py
```

in `main.py`I import `script2.py` the following way :

```
from myPackage.subfolder2 import script2 as script2
```

then, I call a function from `script2.py` in `main.py` with :

```
bar = script2.foo()
```

and in `script2` I need to import a function from `script1` :

```
from ..subfolder1.script11 import my_function
```

and it breaks with the error :

```
attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

I have inspected the `__name__` variable and indeed it has the value `__main__`. How can I manage that properly ?

Comment: Try putting a `__init__.py` in your `myPackage` folder as well.  Also, it should be `from subfolder2 import script2`, you don't need the `.py` there.

Comment: The `__init__` is there in reality I just forgot about it. For the import `script2.py` this was a typo, in my project it is indeed `import script2`. I corrected the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you should have to do is change your import in `main.py` to `from myPackage.subfolder2 import script2`. I set up a directory and some files in this way, using that import, and the script runs as expected:

```
main.py
myPackage/
  subfolder1/
    script11.py
  subfolder2/
    script2.py
```

script11.py

```
def bar():
    return 10
```

script2.py

```
from ..subfolder1.script11 import bar

def foo():
    x = bar()
    print('foo is', x)
```

main.py

```
from myPackage.subfolder2 import script2 as s2

s2.foo()
```

Running:

```
>>> py .\main.py
foo is 10
```

Some notes:

- I'm assuming Python 3, since Python 2 was deprecated beginning of this year
- In Python 3, the `__init__.py` files aren't necessary to make a package, but having them doesn't hurt anything. You can leave them out if you want.
- The `as script2` part in `from subfolder2 import script2 as script2` is redundant. It will already be imported as `script2`.

Comment: Typo on my part again. I corrected the question accordingly. This is already set up as you propose but I still have the error on my side. Indeed it's python 3

Comment: Well I don't get it. I relaunched. Somehow it's working now ... I will accept your answer